# Proof of Probability of Obtaining U in Mann Whitney Test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I am trying to understand how the Probability Formula of U is calculated in this [Paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi8oeiBs6eDAxUXavUHHbiAA9kQFnoECAsQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fprojecteuclid.org%2Fjournals%2Fannals-of-mathematical-statistics%2Fvolume-18%2Fissue-1%2FOn-a-Test-of-Whether-one-of-Two-Random-Variables%2F10.1214%2Faoms%2F1177730491.full&usg=AOvVaw3BNdUHJs2gZD4MafP3rZKR&opi=89978449), Equation 1 from section 4.
[image]
Details:
Suppose we have two groups A and B, each containing m and n samples respectively. U counts the number of times a member from A precedes(ranks above) member from B. $\bar{p}_{\text{nm}}(U)$ be the number of sequences in which there are m A's and n B's, in each of which member of A precedes(ranks above) member of B, U number of times. Then the following recursion formula for $\bar{p}_{\text{nm}}(U)$ is given by:
[image]

1] Could someone please help me derive the above?

Furthermore when doing a test of comparing wherther A and B perform equally or not, the probability of obtaining  $\bar{p}_{\text{nm}}(U)$ under the Null hypothesis that A and B perform equally is given by ${p}_{\text{nm}}(U)$, which has the recursion formula as below:
[image]

2] Could someone please help me derive the above?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you say "help me derive" I'll outline the ideas needed rather than give a complete line by line derivation.

They actually tell you how to do it in the paper, though perhaps it's more succinct than you're used to. A lot of papers are like this -- they tell you what they're doing but you have to fill in some blanks.

Their approach starts with converting the data to a sequence of 1's and 0's, representing the two samples sorted together.

For example, imagine you had these data (sorted), where $n=3$ and $m=4$:

```
x:  17.2    18.4       21.3 
y:               19.5       22.7   28.6  30.1
```

or just representing which sample is which when ordering the data from smallest to largest, that's $\text{x}\, \text{x}\, \text{y}\, \text{x}\, \text{y}\, \text{y}\, \text{y}$. We can compute $U$ by looking at all $x_i,y_j$ pairs and just counting the number of times a $y$ precedes an $x$, which can be done directly from that sequence of $x$'s and $y$'s; in this case only the smallest $y$ precedes any $x$'s.

This corresponds to the sequence `0 0 1 0 1 1 1` (writing a 0 for each $x$ and a 1 for each $y$). If $U$ is the number of times a `1` precedes a `0`, this sample ordering has $U=1$.

More generally, we have some such sequence of $n$ `0` and $m$ `1` values such that a `1` precedes a `0` $U$ times. Now imagine we left out the last value in the list.

Either it was a `1` or a `0` that was omitted.

If it was a `0` then in that shorter sequence we had $n-1$ `0` values and $m$ `1` values and the statistic for that smaller pair of samples had the value $U-m$ (because adding the `0` at the end means all $m$ `1`s precede it, adding $m$ to the count to obtain the value $U$).

If it was a `1` then in that shorter sequence we had $n$ `0` values and $m-1$ `1` values and the statistic had the value $U$ (because the new value doesn't precede any `0`s).

The number of ways to get $U$ with $n,m$ is therefore the number of ways to get the smaller pair of samples of size $n-1,m$  with statistic $U-m$  *plus* the number of ways to get the smaller pair of samples of size $n,m-1$ with statistic $U$.

That's the first recursion you asked about, the one for $\bar{p}$.

With the second, if the null is true, the observations are *exchangeable*. What's the probability that the last element out of $m+n$ observations consisting of $n$ `0`'s and $m$ `1`'s is a `0`? $\frac{n}{n+m}$. Conversely, the chance that it's a `1` is $\frac{m}{n+m}$. By the law of total probability, the second result follows immediately, given the first result.